# Python: Calculate how many days are overlap between 2 dates by id in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I need to know how many days are overlapped in different dates ranges depending on each student_id.

The solution I have until now is:

```
# example data frame

start_dates = pd.date_range('2021-02-24', periods=4, freq='D')
end_dates = pd.date_range('2021-02-24', periods=4, freq='M')

data = {'id':['123456', '123456', '789101', '903456'],
        'starts_on':start_dates,
       'ends_on':end_dates}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Output:
    id  starts_on   ends_on
0   123456  2021-02-24  2021-02-28
1   123456  2021-02-25  2021-03-31
2   789101  2021-02-26  2021-04-30
3   903456  2021-02-27  2021-05-31
```

As you can see, the first and second rows have the same id and the dates are overlapped (the second date starts one day later than the other one and finishes later, so it has an overlap of 4 days). I need a way to do this process for a larger data frame.

My best solution until now is a way to calculate the overlapped days between two days, but I don't know how to iterate this on my dataframe rows having into account that the id has to be the same and then compare the dates to see the overlapped days per id:

```
Range = namedtuple('Range', ['start', 'end'])

r1 = Range(start=datetime(2021, 2, 24), end=datetime(2021, 2, 28))
r2 = Range(start=datetime(2021, 2, 25), end=datetime(2021, 3, 31))
latest_start = max(r1.start, r2.start)
earliest_end = min(r1.end, r2.end)
delta = (earliest_end - latest_start).days + 1
overlap = max(0, delta)
overlap

Output:
4
```

Comment: you can use groupby `df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: (x['ends_on']- x['starts_on'].shift(-1)).dt.days+1).max()`

Comment: Hi @Nagakiran , thanks a lot for your help!! Just one more question, how can I create a new column in my data frame with the result of this groupby?

Comment: you can simply transform the data, and assign result to new column, i just added to answer

Answer (score 2):

If you only have the case of having 2 date ranges per `id` then you can use a simple `groupby` to get the job done.

First, make sure the dates are actual date types in your dataframe by modiying your setup code:

```
start_dates = pd.date_range('2021-02-24', periods=4, freq='D').date
end_dates = pd.date_range('2021-02-24', periods=4, freq='M').date
```

Then you can group by id and get the maximum start dates and minimum end dates to figure out the smallest possible overlap for an id.

```
# we need a function to handle the special case when there's only 1 row per id
def overlap(df):
  if df.shape[0] == 1:
    return 0
  else:
    return (df.ends_on.min() - df.starts_on.max()).days + 1


(
  df
  .groupby(["id"])
  .apply(overlap)
)
```

The result is:

```
id
123456    4
789101    0
903456    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try grouping by ID and use shift to get recent start and subtract with end,

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: (x['ends_on']- x['starts_on'].shift(-1)).dt.days+1).max()
```

#Edit 1

```
res = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: (x['ends_on']- x['starts_on'].shift(-1)).dt.days.add(1).max())
df.set_index('id').assign(newcol=res)
```

out:

```
id  starts_on   ends_on overlap newcol
0   123456  2021-02-24  2021-02-28  NaN 4.0
1   123456  2021-02-25  2021-03-31  NaN 4.0
2   789101  2021-02-26  2021-04-30  NaN NaN
3   903456  2021-02-27  2021-05-31  NaN NaN
```